# How to sort this list using Python

Tags: python

Here is my list, I need to sort this list by uage which is second value in this list, highest to lowest, I used sorted function in Python but still not able to sort it. Here is what I did:

Create list

`list=[['user_hp', '581702031', u'/data/test_list/vol1/jars'], ['user_hp', '20358287286', u'/data/test_list/vol1/preprocessing'], ['user_hp', '5654822268', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/prep_1_pred_full.csv'], ['user_ma', '535416651', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/dr_summaryocto_2015_2018'], ['user_rj', '65858160', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/dr_summaryocto_valid_baseline'], ['user_rj', '91006461', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/dr_summaryocto_valid_baseline_norm'], ['user_rj', '65857281', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/dr_summaryocto_valid_test'], ['user_rj', '91006341', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/dr_summaryocto_valid_test_norm'], ['user_rj', '30919968', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/dr_summarytm_valid_baseline'], ['user_rj', '30471741', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/dr_summarytm_valid_baseline_details'], ['user_rj', '30918279', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/dr_summarytm_valid_test'], ['user_rj', '30472743', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/dr_summarytm_valid_test_details'], ['user_ma', '4085622933', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/exp_on_terr_201912.csv'], ['user_ma', '12', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/mv_spark_test'], ['user_rp', '33798607293', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/points_linref'], ['user_ma', '2048712', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/std_events_table'], ['user_tj', '0', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/trip_summary_dev'], ['user_tj', '101085', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/trip_summary_dev_fixtz_md'], ['user_tj', '101676', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/trip_summary_dev_timezone'], ['user_ma', '0', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/tr_summary_oc_201518_wo500m'], ['user_ma', '35921358528', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/tr_summary_oc_2015_2018'], ['user_rj', '273606066', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/tr_summary_oc_valid_baseline'], ['user_rj', '273606066', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/tr_summary_oc_valid_test'], ['user_rj', '113375118', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/trip_summary_tm_valid_baseline'], ['user_rj', '113375118', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/trip_summary_tm_valid_test'], ['user_ms', '7968', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/u360_driver_summary'], ['user_ms', '7920', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/u360_dr_summaryexclude_brake']]`

Sort the above list using Python function sorted

```
sorted(list,key=lambda l:l[1], reverse=True)
```

I am not getting right results:

`[['user_rj', '91006461', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/dr_summaryocto_valid_baseline_norm'], ['user_rj', '91006341', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/dr_summaryocto_valid_test_norm'], ['user_ms', '7968', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/u360_driver_summary'], ['user_ms', '7920', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/u360_dr_summaryexclude_brake'], ['user_rj', '65858160', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/dr_summaryocto_valid_baseline'], ['user_rj', '65857281', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/dr_summaryocto_valid_test'], ['user_hp', '581702031', u'/data/test_list/vol1/jars'], ['user_hp', '5654822268', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/prep_1_pred_full.csv'], ['user_ma', '535416651', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/dr_summaryocto_2015_2018'], ['user_ma', '4085622933', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/exp_on_terr_201912.csv'], ['user_ma', '35921358528', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/tr_summary_oc_2015_2018'], ['user_rp', '33798607293', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/points_linref'], ['user_rj', '30919968', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/dr_summarytm_valid_baseline'], ['user_rj', '30918279', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/dr_summarytm_valid_test'], ['user_rj', '30472743', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/dr_summarytm_valid_test_details'], ['user_rj', '30471741', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/dr_summarytm_valid_baseline_details'], ['user_rj', '273606066', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/tr_summary_oc_valid_baseline'], ['user_rj', '273606066', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/tr_summary_oc_valid_test'], ['user_ma', '2048712', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/std_events_table'], ['user_hp', '20358287286', u'/data/test_list/vol1/preprocessing'], ['user_ma', '12', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/mv_spark_test'], ['user_rj', '113375118', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/trip_summary_tm_valid_baseline'], ['user_rj', '113375118', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/trip_summary_tm_valid_test'], ['user_tj', '101676', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/trip_summary_dev_timezone'], ['user_tj', '101085', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/trip_summary_dev_fixtz_md'], ['user_tj', '0', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/trip_summary_dev'], ['user_ma', '0', u'/data/test_list/user_listprocess/tr_summary_oc_201518_wo500m']]`

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Those are `string`s not `int`s. Do an int conversion in the function you are using to sort as well:

```
sorted(list,key=lambda l: int(l[1]), reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, one more question can I get top 20 from this sorted list?

Comment: use slicing `sorted(list,key=lambda l: int(l[1]), reverse=True)[:20]` https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/